# ignore touch over a barButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I made a custom split view controller, and I have tried to mimic the standard one as much as possible.

One feature I have is if the device is in portrait and the master view is displayed, if you tap on the details view, the master view will hide.

I use this code in the details view to accomplish this.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Detect touches on the details View and notify the Split View controller
    if(point.y != self.touchLocation.y)
    {

       if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(detailsViewDidTapDetails:)])
            [_delegate detailsViewDidTapDetails:self];
    }
    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}
```

The problem I am having, is if the detailsView is filled with a view that has its own navigation bar, then any buttons pressed in the navigation bar trigger the 'details view tapped' methods displayed above.  This conflicts with adding the 'Show Details' button that you place inside a nav bar.  Essentially what happens, is the methods to hide/show the master View is called twice back to back.

I need a way to ignore any taps on top of my 'hide/show details' button.  I have a reference to the button, I just need to ignore taps on it within my hitTest / pointsInside methods.

Comment: did you try, userInteractionsEnabled method?

Comment: I need the button to be enabled.  I just need to ignore tap detection over it, and let the button use its selector instead.  The tap detection and the button call the same method.  So currently that method gets called twice, and I need it to only be called once.